# using LINQ to filter a List<string> without changing the variable type

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am writing a web crawler in c#. Within the method to get all of the links on a page, i want to return the list of links, but 'filter' it with LINQ so that the list only contains urls that exist. I have a helper method written called RemoteFileExists that returns a boolean value. At the end of the method, I wrote the following LINQ line:

```
//Links is a List<string> that hasn't been filtered
return (from link in Links
                where RemoteFileExists(link)
                select link).ToList<string>();
```

For some reason, when I do this, the List is returned empty.

RemoteFileExists:

```
static bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: What does `RemoteFileExists` look like?

Comment: what if you were to alter that statement and use a foreach loop are you getting any data in Links..? what happens when you debug this code..? Please show all relevant code Method(s) for the issue that you are experiencing

Comment: @Oded Edited into the OP.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what exception you get? Set a breakpoint in the `catch`.

Comment: @JesusSqueegee Have you tried stepping into the debugger to see if your `RemoteFileExists` is executing properly (returning `OK` _and_ not throwing exceptions)?

Comment: Looks like `RemoteFileExists` is returning false. Maybe the server does not support being given `HEAD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess either you links are not correct or your sites don't support `HEAD`. Since this code works

```
List<string> Links = new List<string>() {"http://www.google.com"};
var res = ( from link in Links
            where RemoteFileExists(link)
            select link).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the RemoteFileExists method in my code. Sometimes the program hangs up because the request is not closed. Right now I am using the following code:

```
static bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
  try
  {
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    response.Close();

    return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Also, the above code does not detect redirects. This is important to crawlers because you need to know when to advance to another page, instead of following redirects to the same page.